# Resource handler returned message: "The CIDR '10.0.1.0/22' is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation, cidr

I'm getting this error while trying to create a VPC with a Subnet in CloudFormation.

```
Subnet  CREATE_FAILED   Resource handler returned message: "The CIDR '10.0.1.0/22' is invalid. (Service: Ec2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 97af4b96-80dd-4092-910c-5d11e5b9ca72, Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: bed19eb5-2309-589e-98bf-9dacc656462a, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

Here it is my VPC and Subnet setup in yaml:

```
VPC:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC'
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.2.0/24
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 45e7f38e-c4b6-4a19-9d54-b74e36ef53de
  Subnet:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.1.0/22
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 58cd6d64-1f79-4dbe-a981-c9238975f154
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/22` CIDR block covers 1024 hosts. Therefore the IP address block has to start a 1024 block boundary.

`10.0.1.0/22` is an IP address that belong to IP address space `10.0.0.1 - 10.0.3.254`. Therefore `10.0.1.0` is not a valid starting address for `/22` subnet.

Some example valid blocks for `/22` size are:

`10.0.0.0/22`
`10.0.4.0/22`
`10.0.8.0/22`

Comment: I changed the network to a /24 network but the error remains :(

Comment: Please update the configuration you tried to the question and the error.

Comment: I put the same network as my VPC and it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The message is correct. 10.0.1.0 is not a valid base address for a /22 network.
The nearest legal values are 10.0.0.0 and 10.0.4.0.

Consider the binary representation of 10.0.1.0 and a /22 netmask:

```
10.0.1.0 = 00001010 00000000 00000001 00000000
/22      = 11111111 11111111 11111100 00000000
```

You can see that at the end of the third octet there is a bit set in the address which is clear in the mask.
This is illegal.

Comment: I changed the network to a /24 network but the error remains :(

Comment: Please quote the new error message.